# Solve $x^2-|5x-3|-x<2,\ \ x\in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

> Solve $x^2-|5x-3|-x<2,\ \ x\in \mathbb{R} $

I tried $x^2-|5x-3|-x<2$  ,

case $1$ ,  $x^2-(5x-3)-x<2,\ x\geq 0 \\
x^2-6x+1<0 \\
3-2\sqrt2 < 3+2\sqrt2 \\
 0.17<x<5.8\\
$

$x^2-(5x-3)-x<2$  ,

case $2$ ,  $x^2+(5x-3)-x<2,\ x< 0 \\
x^2+4x-5<0 \\
-5 < x< 1\\
$

The region common is $3-2\sqrt2<x<1$

But the book gives answer $-5<x<3+2\sqrt2$ .  I am confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case 1 is not for $x>0$ but for $5x-3>0\implies x>\frac{3}{5}$

So for case 1 you have $\frac{3}{5}<x<3+\sqrt{2}$ (since $\frac{3}{5}>3-\sqrt{2}$

For case 2 you have $x<\frac{3}{5}$, so $-5<x<\frac{3}{5}$

So the general solution is $-5<x<3+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Case 1 should be $5x - 3 \color{red}{\geq} 0$, so $x \color{red}{\geq} \frac{3}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can see why you need to discard the two solutions if you rearrange the equation to

$x^2-x-2<|5x-3|$

and draw them both.

When you solve for 
$x^2-x-2<5x-3$  you must only take into account that $x>\frac 35$

Similarily for 
$x^2-x-2<-5x+3$  you must only take into account that $x<\frac 35$

This is what makes the V-shape for the absolute value.

Then you only want the solutions where the y-values of the parabola are less than the y-values of the absolute value.

See http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1536031
Click on "Show Lines" box to see the two discarded solutions at point A and B.